# Am I using "quip" correctly?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

Lester B. Pearson, a famous Canadian politician, once said

> Foreign policy is domestic policy with a hat on.

Is this a quip? If not what word would fit my sentence

> Lester B. Pearson's ___, "Foreign policy is domestic policy with a hat on."

Right now I have quip.

Comment: https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/bon_mot.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a 'quip' is a brief, light-hearted, humorous statement. Quips are not deep or side-splitting. There are other words you could use also to describe the quote, but quip is not wrong.
Dictionaries say quip is a 'clever' or 'humorous' remark; some definitions emphasize 'teasing' or 'taunting', but I don't see that as as a requirement in common usage of 'quip'.